# Best practice to pass data from a controller to another non child or parent controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to angular, after using a video tutorial and reading some documentation, I decided to rebuild an old app of mine as an example with angularjs.

So this app has a table showing some data. It has a form underneath which helps you modify the data from the list. You have a button on each line which allows you to edit the line, it then fill all the fields in the form and you can then save or cancel your changes.

I made a controller to handle the list, it works fine, it gets a json from http.
I used ng-click on my edit button to trigger a function in this controller, giving it the whole object it's supposed to edit.

I made a controller to handle the form in which the edit should take place and I don't really found a 'non-hacky' way to pass the data from the list controller to the form controller.

So, my question is : what is the best practice and/or the common way to get this data from my list controller to my form controler ?

Comment: I'd pass the data via a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you are using the form controller. If it's being used within a template using `ng-controller` attribute, then this controller has access to parent scope, so you can work with list controller's data. (although note some scope-inheritance quirks solved by "dot notation", explained nicely by egghead.io: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot)

If you're launching your edit form in a another url (e.g. `/items/2/edit`) and handle it in a routing configuration, then you can use `resolve` property to pass any data to the controller: [$routeProvider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the entire object as parameter

```
<row ng-repeat="theModelInRow in modelList" ng-click="edit(theModelInRow)">
```

Comment: that's what I'm doing right now, except the edit function is in my list controller, and I don't know how to feed the data to my form controller. I'll check rawry's answer to see if it fits my needs. From a swift survey of the page, it seems to be what I want to do.

Comment: It is right. Dont separate the functions in detal controller or list controller, you should separate it based on model. You should have a unique controller.

Answer (score 0):

if form controller isn't a nested controller of list controller on view, then you can use rootScope.